# Buttons in an input field

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

How to make the following (it looks like i can keyin multiple texts and fit into an input):
Anyone has any idea what is this called?

[image]

Comment: You mean like tag editions below SO questions ? Have a look at the elements and the source ;)

Comment: but be an input field? use `div` can or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe [this plugin](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/)
will help you.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another plugin that actually has a drop down so you can search tags perhaps

http://devthought.com/wp-content/projects/mootools/textboxlist/Demo/